# what "type" is an option chosen from a select tag

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and attempting get the value of an option chosen from a select tag. I am familiar with some types of input such as radio, text, checkboxes e.t.c. my question is what "type" is an option chosen from a select tag. The first three forms work just fine but not the fourth 
here is my code

```
<form action = display.php method="get">
input first name:
<input type=text name=fname><br>
input last name:
<input type=text name=lname><br>
<input type=submit value="Click">
</form>

<form name="input"
action=radio.php method="get">
Username:<input type="text" name="user">
<br>
<input type=radio name=card_type value="visa ">
Visa <br>
<input type=radio name=card_type value="mc">
Master Card <br>
<input type="radio" name=card_type value="discover">
Discover <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<form name="gender"
action=gender.php method="get">
<input type=radio name=gender_type value="male">
Male <br>
<input type=radio name=gender_type value="female">
Female <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<form name="chosen_party" action=party.php method="get">
<select>
<option type=text  name=party_type value="democrat">Democrat</option>
<option type=text  name=party_type value="republican">Republican</option>
<option type=text  name=party_type value="independent">Independent</option>
<option type=text  name=party_type value="undecided">Undecided</option> 
</select>
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the PHP file for the fourth form...

```
<?php
$party_select = $_GET['party_type'];
echo "User has chosen $party_select";
?>
```

Comment: Besides answers given, `<option>` does not have a `type=text`; you can safely remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give a name to select tag. and in the case of option give a value to each option. like this..

```
<form name="chosen_party" action=party.php method="get">
<select name="party_type">
<option   value="democrat">Democrat</option>
<option   value="republican">Republican</option>
<option   value="independent">Independent</option>
<option   value="undecided">Undecided</option> 
</select>
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in the php there is a little syntax problem. You have to put $party_select outside of the quote. The code should be..

```
<?php
$party_select = $_GET['party_type'];
echo 'User has chosen '.$party_select;
?>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: `<option>` does not have a `type=text`

Comment: *"You have to put $party_select outside of the quote."* - What the OP has is fine, he's using the variable inside double quotes. Had he used `echo 'User has chosen $party_select';` in single quotes, then that would not have worked. Variables get parsed in double quotes, but not in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the name attribute to the select, not the options.

```
<form name="chosen_party" action="party.php" method="get">
    <select name="party_type">
        <option value="democrat">Democrat</option>
        <option value="republican">Republican</option>
        <option value="independent">Independent</option>
        <option value="undecided">Undecided</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in php, you can access `$_GET['party_type']`, which will be the option that was chosen.

Comment: No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

option says that it is an option. Don't need the type attribute at all.

```
<select name="myOptionList">
  <option value="1">First option</option>
  <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>
```

this is enough markup, more here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp